# special Aronszajn trees

Tags: set-theory, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

I have found two different definitions for Aronszajn special trees: somewhere they say they are Aronszajn trees where there exists a strictly increasing function from the tree to the rational numbers, somewhere else they say they are Aronszajn trees which are union of $\omega$ antichains.

What's the difference between the two definition? And in case they are equivalent, why are they? Because I can't figure it out.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Two definitions of special Aronszajn tree are equivalent. You may refer the exercise in Jech's set theory.

Comment: thank you! I will think it over and consult Jech, then.

Comment: For any partially ordered set $P$ (not necessarily a tree) there is a strictly increasing function $f:P\to\mathbb Q$ if and only if $P$ is the union of countably many antichains, where antichain means "set of pairwise incomparable elements". The proof is quite easy, just think about it.

Comment: If you end up not seeing the details, you may want to consult [MR0776625](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=776625)
Stevo Todorčević, *Trees and linearly ordered sets*. In **Handbook of set-theoretic topology**, 235–293, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1984.

Comment: @any_one: The non-trivial direction of the equivalence that **bof** mentioned is proved in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/168008/12042).